# Error building c++ project with ppconsul(Consul client for c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, consul

I'm a beginner to cpp and trying to use a cpp library called ppconsul(https://github.com/oliora/ppconsul ). This library has dependency to some of other libraries like (boost and curl). I have build ppconsul with all its dependencies and trying to use ppconsul executable in a new project. When I try to build the new project, I'm getting some linker issue like below.

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual char const * **thiscall ppconsul::BadStatus::what(void)const " (?what@BadStatus@ppconsul@@UBEPBDXZ)
1>ConsulApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl ppconsul::helpers::encodeUrl(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (?encodeUrl@helpers@ppconsul@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV34@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ppconsul::parameters::detail::printParameter(class std::basic_ostream > &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,struct ppconsul::kw::dc_keyword**)" (??$printParameter@Udc_keyword__@kw@ppconsul@@@detail@parameters@ppconsul@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@4@Udc_keyword__@kw@2@@Z)

I tried to link the project and change the visual studio but nothing worked. Anybody has any idea about this linker issue? 
TIA,
Prassi

Comment: Issue resolved-  Refer this thread
https://github.com/oliora/ppconsul/issues/24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved- Refer this thread github.com/oliora/ppconsul/issues/24

**build ppconsul as a static library by passing -DBUILD_STATIC_LIB=ON to CMake.**